# How to remove Address?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to reply to the original email sender and also to keep and reply in CC to all the email ddresses that are in CC in the original email.

```vb
Sub estimate()
    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
       
    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Utils\Outlook_Templates\Estimate.oft")
       
    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Subject = "RE: " + origEmail.Subject
    replyEmail.To = origEmail.Sender
    replyEmail.CC = origEmail.CC + ";" + replyEmail.CC
    replyEmail.Display
End Sub
```

This is working. However in the CC I often have some contact (for example: John Doe) which I'd like to remove when I reply.

I'd like to keep every email address except for the John Doe (in CC).

EDIT: Additionally, when I use this to reply to an email it repeats the email address in the "To" and in the "CC". This is because I already have a defined email in the "To" in the "template". Anyway, lets say this is repeating "My Boss" in the "To" and in the "CC". How can I remove it from the "CC"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should work:**

```
Sub estimate()
    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    Dim s() As String
    Dim add As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Utils\Outlook_Templates\Estimate.oft")

    s = Split(origEmail.CC & ";" & replyEmail.CC, ";")

    For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)

        If InStr(1, s(i), "John Doe") = 0 Then
            add = add & ";" & s(i)

         End If
    Next


    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Subject = "RE: " + origEmail.Subject
    replyEmail.To = origEmail.Sender
    replyEmail.CC = add
    replyEmail.Display


End Sub
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Just one more thing: when I use this to reply to an email it repeats the email address in the "to" and in the "CC". This is because I already have a defined email in the "to" in the "template" Anyway, lets say this is repeating "My Boss" in the "to" and in the "CC". How can I remove it from the "CC" ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually according to the [**Official Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.cc), you aren't meant to modify the `.CC` property directly:

> This property contains the display names only. The [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection should be used to modify the CC recipients.

The proper way to do it then would be:

```vb
Dim i as Long

' If the address could occur multiple times, start at the end & work backwards
For i = replyEmail.Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    If LCase(replyEmail.Recipients(i).Name) = LCase("John Doe") Then
        replyEmail.Recipients.Remove(i)
    End If
Next

replyEmail.Display
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of setting up each property manually, I'd recommend using the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)) method of the `MailItem` class which creates a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message. Then you may set up properties as you need.

Second, I'd recommend dealing with the `Recipients` collection if you need to set up recipients (change, add or remove). The corresponding property of the `MailItem` class returns a [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item.

Finally, you may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.